# Make AWS API Gateway with Lambda Invocation return 413 Payload Too Large

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am currently using AWS API Gateway in combination with a lambda invocation. This is working perfectly, as long as I stay withing the known [AWS Lambda Limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html). One of the calls receives a file via a POST request, so that goes fine as long as the file is < 6 MB.

However when the file is too large, I get a 502 Bad Gateway response. This is not really helpful to the client, I would rather return a 413 Payload Too Large. How can I do this? I haven't found a way so far, looking at the API Gateway options.

Comment: More than that, API Gateway has limits too: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html - Payload size Max 10Mb

Comment: I think, you need to validate the file's size before sending any request to the API Gateway endpoint.  My approach to avoid this kind of problems is working with API Gateway + Lambda + s3.

Comment: Accoding to the doc, API Gateway is already supposed to return a 413 : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/supported-gateway-response-types.html it should work with a file > 10 MB :)

Comment: Note that the [Lambda limit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html) for synchronous Invoke request payload is only 6MB.  There seems to be an edge case that one might expect to occur between 6 and 10MB.  Lambda should be throwing back a 413 to API Gateway, but API Gateway might be translating that to a 502 [because Lambda isn't returning the expected response](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=760018) format.  (Speculation.)

Comment: Seems like you are correct Michael, the logs do mention an incorrect response format. I am unsure how to get this fixed thoug, since it is generated by AWS.

Comment: anyone ever figure this out?

Comment: We've chosen to create a signed S3 URL for our application to upload the file, rather than POSTing it via API Gateway + Lambda. There is no way to change the 10MB API Gateway or 6MB Lambda limit.